# Problems in installing package stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I tried to install the package stringr but failed for several times.

The error shows:

> library(stringr)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/R/R.4.0.3/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
> /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/Cluster-Apps/R/R.4.0.3/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so)

I also tried to install stringi but failed as well for the same error.

Does anyone know how what happened and how can I deal with it? Thank you so much!

Comment: What version of R are you using?  Typically it's either too old or (occasionally) very very new versions of R that cause such issues.

Comment: If you could include the output of `Sys.info()`, that'd be great!

Comment: Many thanks! My R version is 4.0.3

Comment: Thank you so much! Here is the info 
> Sys.info()
                             sysname                              release 
                             "Linux"        "3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64" 
                             version                             nodename 
"#1 SMP Tue Mar 7 15:41:52 UTC 2023"                   "login-web-node-9" 
                             machine                                login 
                            "x86_64"                            "unknown" 
                                user                       effective_user

Comment: that's not *that* old, but maybe it causes some issues. Would you be able to update R and see if that helps?

Comment: See: https://bootstrappers.umassmed.edu/bootstrappers-courses/courses/rCourse/Additional_Resources/Updating_R.html#updating-r

Comment: Sometimes it helps to `remove.packages('stringr')` and then to try to install.